# WordPress/Gutenberg block example preview don't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I use Gutenberg with WordPress.

I'm trying to use `example` property to show an image in the block preview area. But I got a preview of a block itself (this is not my image but how the field is in the editor).

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/#example-optional

What's wrong please ? Can I have some help ?

[image]

```
registerBlockType( 'ccn/gut-text-title', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: __( 'Titre', 'ccn-gut' ),
    category: 'text',
    icon: blockIcons.text_title,
    keywords: [ __( 'titre', 'ccn-gut' ) ],
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: '.gut-hook-text'
        },
    },
    example: {
        attributes: {
            cover: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg',
        },
    },
    edit: Edit,
    save,
} )
```

I tried with basics attributes. Same result...

```
example: {
        attributes: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            textColor: '#FFFFFF',
            title: __( 'I am a test', 'ccn-gut' ),
        },
    },
```

I Tried with code sample example too :

```
example: {
    attributes: {
        cover: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg',
    },
    innerBlocks: [
        {
            name: 'core/paragraph',
            attributes: {
                content: __(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et eros eu felis.'
                ),
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

I followed this tutorial without any success :
https://mediaron.com/how-to-enable-gutenberg-block-previews/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gutenberg basically just renders your block as you define it in the `edit` and `save` functions, so if the image isn't showing up, you likely haven't told Gutenberg where/how you'd like the image to appear.

Looking at the code you provided, it looks like you haven't defined a `cover` attribute on the `ccn/gut-text-title` block you are registering. You'll need to add that to the `attributes` object, e.g.:

```js
attributes: {
  content: {
    type: 'string',
    source: 'html',
    selector: '.gut-hook-text'
  },
  cover: {
    type: 'string',
  },
},
```

Then, in your `edit` and `save` functions you'll need to define how that `cover` attribute should be displayed, e.g.:

```js
edit: ( { attributes } ) => {
  const {
    cover,
  } = attributes;

  return (
    <img src={ cover }/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for all your helps. I use an `edit.js` external file. I put a RichText component in `return()`. If I add the `<img>` tag it will be show in Gutenberg editor right ? I don't understand where I can put `<img src={ cover }/>`? I will edit my post with my real structure. The `example` property is not use finally ?

Comment: Whatever you add to the `edit` function's `return` will be displayed in the editor. Whatever you add to the `save` function's `return` is what ultimately will be rendered on the frontend of the site. Ideally the two are pretty much the same (e.g. you'd have the `img` tag in both your `edit` and `save` functions. [Here is a very simplified example of an `edit`/`save` pattern I use regularly](https://pastebin.com/G8YsbM7y).

Comment: I tried to add an `img`, explained to me in `edit` and I see it in the preview and in the `editor`. Isn't there a way to do the preview directly in example `property` with the use of `innerBlocks`?

Comment: You can use `example` with `innerBlocks`, but the block you registered in your example code (`ccn/gut-text-title`) isn't using `innerBlocks`, so that won't work in your case.

Comment: Okay. I used `InnerBlocks` in `example` property. I added `InnerBlocks` in `edit.js`, I got the preview. It's a good start. The problem now is that `InnerBlocks` appears in Gutenberg Editor (I know it's normal because `edit.js` render on Editor side). So how can I use `Innerblocks` only in the preview and hide it on the Editor?

Comment: I don't think you can, nor do I think you would want to. The `example` property is specifically supposed to show a preview of your actual block. If you are using `InnerBlocks` _only_ in the preview, that isn't accurately reflecting your block and it's capabilities. If your block doesn't support `InnerBlocks` you shouldn't be using it in your preview. If you want your block to have an image, you can use many of the other tools Gutenberg offers for working with media (see the example I linked above).

Comment: Okay but I would like to use an image only for the preview (`example` property) and not to display in the Editor (`edit.js`). I followed this tutorial but it don't work : https://mediaron.com/how-to-enable-gutenberg-block-previews/